# .htaccess is being read but not working

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to make a redirection from an old URL `https://www.mywebsite.eu/en/form/emsos-2017/` to the homepage `https://www.mywebsite.eu/`.

I do not have access to the webserver but I know that the language prefix (in this case `/en`) is managed by the CodeIgniter framework.

`mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite` are enabled.

So I already tried that but none worked.

```
Redirect https://www.mywebsite.eu/en/form/emsos-2017 https://www.mywebsite.eu
RewriteRule ^emsos-2017/ https://www.mywebsite.eu [R=301,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/emsos-2017$ http://www.mywebsite.eu
```

I know that the .htaccess is read because when I make a typo I have an **Internal Server Error**.

I also tried to redirect 404 error but this is not working.

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.mywebsite.eu/404/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give full URI without domain name in pattern of `RedirectMatch`.

Try this rule before any other rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[a-z]{2}/form/emsos-2017/?$ /
```

Comment: This works great. But how can I handle a multilingual website? I mean the `/en` could be `/sp` or `/fr` depending where the user come from. How to use a wildcard in a RedirectMatch ?

Comment: It work like a charm, thanks! By the way, what does the `{2}` ?

Comment: That is a quantifier which means match 2 of given group or a character.